# Vue.js Two-Way sync Data Binding using vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, two-way-binding

I'm using Vue.js with TypeScript and the `vue-property-decorator`. I'd like to perform some two-way data binding between a parent and child component. Here is a simple idea of what I'm trying to do:

### Parent Component

```
<template>
  <progress :is-loaded.sync="isLoaded"/>
</template>

@Component
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  get isLoaded() { return Store.getters["isLoaded"]; }
  set isLoaded(value: boolean) { Store.commit("isLoaded", value); }
}
```

### Child Component

```
<template>
 <progress :value="_value" min="0" max="100"></progress>
 {{_isLoaded}}
</template>

@Component
export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  public isLoaded: boolean;

  public _isLoaded: boolean;
  public _value: number;

  public mounted() {
    this._isLoaded = this.isLoaded;
    this._value = this.value;
  }

  @Watch("isLoaded")
  public onIsLoadedChanged() {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      // Animate _value from 0 to 100.
      this._isLoaded = true;
      this.$emit("update:isLoaded", this._isLoaded);
    }
  }
}
```

Do I really have to use two fields `isLoaded` and `_isLoaded` as well as use `this.$emit` with a magic string of `update:isLoaded`? All of this syntax seems very verbose, is there a simpler way? Is there some way to encapsulate some of this?

Answer (score 0):

At what point in your app does the value of `isLoaded` change? If it only changes in the parent, you don't need to emit an event back up, and you can just use the prop without the `@Watch` and without the `_isLoaded` variable. 
If isLoaded changes in the child, you don't need the prop and the duplicate variable. You can just emit a `loaded` event and listen for that event in the parent.

This is a simplified example where the style of the child changes when the parent changes `isLoaded`

**parent**

```
<template>
  <progress :is-loaded="isLoaded"/>
</template>

@Component
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  public isLoaded: boolean = false
  created(){
    setInterval(()=>this.updateStatus(), 500)
  }
  this.updateStatus(){
    this.isLoaded = true
  }
}
```

**child**

```
<template>
 <div :class="{ full: isLoaded }">Loaded is {{ isLoaded }}</div>
</template>

@Component
export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  isLoaded: boolean;
}

<css>
   .full {width:100%}
</css>
```

Comment: It can change both in the parent and the child. The parent can change it at any time but the child will run some animation and then set it to `false`.

Comment: In that case I think you did it correctly :) But you might consider if it's good architecture to have a status change in multiple components. Why would a progress bar be able to change the loaded status? It should only display the status...

Comment: I'm trying to model a progress bar in an intermediate state i.e. when `isLoaded` is set to false in the parent, it animates another `value` property from 0 to 100 but never reaches 100. Eventually `isLoaded` is set to true in the parent and the `value` property is set to 100. Alternatively, the parent can change the `value` instead. I'd love to know if I'm thinking about this wrong.

Comment: Just updated the example, it seems I have to use `mounted` instead of `this._isLoaded = this.isLoaded`.

Comment: Ideally, you should try to keep the `state` in one component only. The function of the child should be to display the state of the parent, and nothing else. (at least in an ideal world). Why do you want your progress bar to make decisions on its own :)

Comment: `isLoaded` and `value` are both related. I'm using Vuex in the parent and want any component in the app to be able to decide which of those properties they want to use via Vuex.

Comment: As I understand it (but I haven't tested), if you use VueX, all your components can just subscribe to VueX and send events to VueX. They don't need to listen to each other at all.